# Finding common elements, ignoring duplicates, in two given string arrays

Tags: java, beginner, strings, programming-challenge, array

I am going through the CodingBat exercises for Java. [Here is the one I have just completed](http://codingbat.com/prob/p100369):

> Start with two arrays of strings, `a` and `b`, each in alphabetical order, possibly with duplicates. Return the count of the number of strings which appear in both arrays. The best "linear" solution makes a single pass over both arrays, taking advantage of the fact that they are in alphabetical order.

Here is my code:

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b){

    String[] shortArray;
    String[] longArray;

    if (a.length != b.length) {
        shortArray = a.length < b. length ? a : b;
        longArray = a.length > b. length ? a : b;
    } else {
        shortArray = a;
        longArray = b;
    }

    int count = 0;
    String letterToAvoid = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < shortArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < longArray.length; j++) {
            if (shortArray[i] == longArray[j] && longArray[j] != letterToAvoid){
                count++;
                letterToAvoid = longArray[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a better - or more efficient - way to find the longest and shortest `array` lengths (and subsequently assign them separately if the lengths are equal)?
2. Is my `letterToAvoid` idea, used to 'skip' certain array elements, good for this kind of exercise?
3. How could I make this code more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one major flaw in your code: Testing strings for value
equality must be done with `.equals()` not with `==`.
For example, for

```
commonTwo(new String[]{new String("a"),"b","c"},
          new String[]{"a","b","c"})
```

your code returns `2` instead of `3`. 
(Compare [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).)

Your computation of the larger/shorter array can be simplified to

```
shortArray = a.length < b.length ? a : b;
longArray = a.length >= b.length ? a : b;
```

But actually your code does not take advantage of the fact that one array is shorter than the other, so you might as well loop over `a`
and `b` directly.

Your `letterToAvoid` idea works (almost) to skip duplicate elements, but I would call the variable differently, perhaps `lastDuplicate`.
And you could early-return from the inner loop if a duplicate is found.
Your idea does not work if the string arrays contain empty strings
as well which should also be counted.

Your solution is not efficient. It does not take advantage of the
fact that both arrays are *sorted*. Instead of a nested loop you
can perform a parallel single iteration over both arrays:

- If current left element is smaller than current right element,
  advance left position by one.
- If current right element is smaller, advance right position.
- If current left and right elements are equal, we have found
  a duplicate. Skip following equal elements in both arrays.

Possible implementation:

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b){

    int count = 0;

    int i = 0;  // Index into a
    int j = 0;  // Index into b

    while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
        int cmp = a[i].compareTo(b[j]);
        if (cmp < 0) {
            // a[i] is smaller
            i++;
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            // b[j] is smaller
            j++;
        } else {
            // a[i] == b[j] 
            // Increment count and skip duplicates
            count++;
            String lastDuplicate = a[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            while (i < a.length && a[i].equals(lastDuplicate)) { i++; }
            while (j < b.length && b[j].equals(lastDuplicate)) { j++; }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: On previous exercises I did actually take advantage of the fact they were sorted. Not sure why I didn't do it this time around. Also not sure why I didn't use `equals`. Your code helped me see it from a different angle. Thanks for pointing these thing out to me.